# Rails 3 Modifying updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a CourseEnrollment model and whenever a user views the course, I want to update the database with the current timestamp. Should I just update the existing updated_at field or create a seperate field for the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd create a separate field. `updated_at` doesn't really correctly communicate its purpose. Something like `last_viewed_at` would be more appropriate. Of course, `updated_at` will be updated when you update `last_viewed_at`, so you need to find a way to override that when all you want to do is update that column.

You can temporarily disable timestamp updating by setting `self.record_timestamps` to false in a `before_filter` and then re-enabling it in an `after_filter`.

Comment: I think there is a better way but you can an toggle `CourseEnrollment.record_timestamps = false` before updating the record.

Comment: I'd go with the extra column, too. To not modify the updated timestamp, add an extra model method, maybe called "viewed!", and put there a call: "update_attribute :last_viewed_at, Time.now". This will just update this field. In your controllers showing the record, just call "record.viewed!" then.

Answer (score 11):

Check out the AR `touch` method http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091311/touch-updated-at-column-in-rails-2-3-2 for more details

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to create a column in CourseEnrollment called last_viewed_at that is set whenever a user views a recored?

If you want to do that, create a migration to add last_viewed_at column to your CourseEnrollment (don't overwrite the rails updated_at field). Then Either in your controller logic or in the model level you can update that field. It depends on how you want it implemented.