# Rails AR callbacks - :after_touch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

How does the :after_touch? callback work? Is it supported in Rails 2.3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touch is supported in rails 2.3.x: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091311/touch-updated-at-column-in-rails-2-3-2)
I'm unsure whether after_touch is supported before 3.0.0 as I believe its part of the "after" method. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/touch

Answer (score 0):

```
in Active record callback 

after_touch do |user|
    puts "You have touched an object"
  end
end
```

as far as my understanding this mean that when ever we want to do with some object then after touch will be called if defined