# Rails timestamp saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application hat requires some updating every 5 minutes and I've got this in the application controller:

```
# update last action & yet to implement updating vitals
def page_update
  if current_user
    current_user.last_page_load = DateTime.now
    interval = 300
    ime_difference = Time.now.to_i - current_user.vitals_update
    updates = time_difference / interval
    # use updates as a multiplier here for any data

    current_user.vitals_update = Time.now.to_i
    current_user.save
  end
end
```

The intention is to store a timestamp of the last update and calculate the multiplier for any changes. Some reason I'm having problems with the timestamps and I don't know what to do.

I've tried outputting the values with no luck, it seems when I try and set

```
current_user.vitals_update = Time.now.to_i
```

I get an error that says

> undefined method `change' for 387426:Fixnum

Comment: What is vitals_update? Is it defined as a method in User or an attribute of User?

Comment: There is a typo in your example.  ime_difference = Time.now.to_i - current_user.vitals_update, should be time_difference.  If the same is in your actual code, it could be causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task, it is better to use rails `touch` method, as stated in this answer.
["Touch" updated_at column in Rails 2.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091311/touch-updated-at-column-in-rails-2-3-2)